# How do I update two tables that have a reference table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables.

```
1. Users 4 Cols
UserID - UserName - RealName - Flags

2. UsersGroups 2 Cols
UserID - GroupID

3. Groups 3 Cols
GroupID - GroupName - Flags
```

What I want to do is select a specific UserName ie USERA and update the Flags column.
but I also want to update the Flags column in the Groups table to the same value.

The only connection I have between the 2 tables is the UsersGroups table.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Inner join will take more time and it will effect the run time of the application and the query

Comment: That should not be significant if the tables are suitably indexed.

Comment: Nobody is mentioning the danger of your data's integrity with their solutions, beware.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Create Proc spUpdateUsersFlag(@UserName as Varchar(32), @Flags as int)
 AS
Declare @UserID as int

BEGIN Transaction
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @UserID = UserID 
        From Users 
        Where UserName = @UserName
    UPDATE Users
        SET Flags = @Flags
        WHERE UserID = @UserID
    UPDATE Groups
        SET Flags = @Flags
        FROM Groups G INNER JOIN UserGroups UG ON G.GroupId = UG.GroupID
        WHERE UG.UserID = @UserID
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT
    -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
    -- capture information for RAISERROR.
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    -- Rollback the failed transaction
    ROLLBACK;
    -- Raise an error: with the original error information.
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, 1);
END CATCH
COMMIT Transaction;
```

EDIT: Corrected an error in the second query.

Comment: ooops!
                WHERE @UserID = @UserName

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE statement can only update records of a single table.

```
UPDATE Users SET Flags = @Flags WHERE UserID = @UserID

UPDATE Groups SET Flags = @Flags
FROM Groups
INNER JOIN UsersGroups ON UsersGroups.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
WHERE UsersGroups.UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: What happens when there's an error between the two updates? (sorry to pick on you but you're at the top, this is aimed at everyone with the same answer too)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.Users
SET Flags = @var
WHERE UserName = 'UserA'

UPDATE g
SET g.Flags = @var
FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

Comment: If I do :
Select * FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
then I get the right info.

But if I try the update I get the error:
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'Flags'.

Comment: Ok done it
Select g.Flags FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'

Comment: Actually that didnt work, it set all my flags in the table to @Var

Comment: Which table? Groups? if USERA is in all groups then that will happen.

Comment: @HollyStyles - he posted another question here which was answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138239/ambiguous-column-name-error-how-do-i-fix-it/1138252#1138252

Answer (score 0):

With respect to select a specific user use the following :

```
select UserName from Users where UserID = <USERA>
```

And updatting the flag column in both 2 tables Users and Groups do the following :

```
update Users set Flags = <Your Flag> where UserID = <USERA>
update Groups set Flags = <Your Flag> where GroupID in (select GroupID from UsersGroups where UserID = <USERA>)
```

Hope that these are useful

Answer (score 0):

That should really be an atomic unit of work to maintain your data integrity!!! When updating more than one table and they must be kept in sync use BEGIN and COMMIT/ROLLBACK TRAN or if you have Sql Server 2008 use the new TRY CATCH syntax

```
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE dbo.Users
    SET Flags = @var
    WHERE UserName = 'UserA'

    UPDATE dbo.Groups
    SET Flags = @var
    FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
    WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRAN
```

As an aside if your data is denormalised for performance then this is your best solution. If that's not the case I recommend you ditch one of the columns. (Waits for typical "It's not my schema I inherited it.. legacy blah... he he :))

PS the code inside the transaction block is flagrantly copy/pasted from Chris' answer.

**EDIT**

There's a lot of comments about ambiguous column names, but there's nothing wrong with the TSQL here. Here is an entire DML and QUERY that I have tested in MSSMS:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 

TABLE_NAME='Users')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Users
    (
        UserID      INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        UserName    NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        RealName    NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        Flags       NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
    )
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ix.name FROM sys.indexes ix WHERE ix.name='IX_Users_UserName')
BEGIN
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Users_UserName ON Users(UserName)
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='Groups')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Groups
    (
        GroupID     INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        GroupName   NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        Flags       NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
    )
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='UsersGroups')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE UsersGroups
    (
        UserID  INT NOT NULL,
        GroupID INT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_UsersGroups PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID, GroupID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_UsersGroups_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_UsersGroups_GroupID FOREIGN KEY (GroupID) REFERENCES Groups(GroupID),
    )
END
GO

DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users)
IF @count = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users(UserName, RealName, Flags)
    SELECT 'USERA', 'User A', 'Flags A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'USERB', 'User B', 'Flags B'
END

SELECT @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Groups)
IF @count = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Groups(GroupName, Flags)
    SELECT 'Group A', 'Flags A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Group B', 'Flags B'
END

SELECT @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UsersGroups)
IF @count = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UsersGroups(GroupID, UserID)
    SELECT 1, 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2
END
GO

BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(16)
        SET @var = 'New Flags A'

        UPDATE dbo.Users
        SET Flags = @var
        WHERE UserName = 'UserA'

        UPDATE dbo.Groups
        SET Flags = @var
        FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
        WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRAN

SELECT Flags FROM Users

SELECT Flags FROM Groups
```

Comment: you're correct to highlight the use of transactions here. however I nitpick back ;) and point out you assume that UserName has a unique constraint. UserID certainly is a PK in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, fair comment. Being really really picky, we don't have the DML. So, we don't actually know UserID is a primary key for certain either.