# Ambiguous column name error, how do I fix it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
1. Users 4 Cols
UserID - UserName - RealName - Flags

2. UsersGroups 2 Cols
UserID - GroupID

3. Groups 3 Cols
GroupID - GroupName - Flags
```

What I want to do is select a specific **UserName** ie USERA and update the Flags column. but I also want to update the Flags column in the Groups table to the same value.

```
UPDATE dbo.Users
SET Flags = @var
WHERE UserName = 'UserA'

UPDATE dbo.Groups
SET Flags = @var
FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

but I keep getting : Ambiguous column name 'Flags'.

if I do Set Groups.Flags = @Var
i get :
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Groupy.Flags" could not be bound.

Comment: The answers that say use g.Flags are incorrect since you cant use an alias in that part of the UPDATE... you need to use Groups.Flags... the error is because when you do the join its getting confused on whether to update the Flags from Users or Groups

Comment: @Chris, I frequently use table aliases in the set clause, but there are rules to be followed to allow that.

Comment: I get the same error regardless of if I use g or Groups...

Comment: @David - are you using MS SQL? Do you have a reference to allow that?

Comment: Alan - see my answer below... try that

Comment: Ah, ive just realised, its because Im trying to set the flags to
SET dbo.Group.Flags = dbo. Group.Flags | 512

Answer (score 18):

You need to add the alias for the Groups table. Change this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Groups
SET Flags = @var
FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

To this:

```
UPDATE g -- change dbo.Groups here to simply 'g'
SET g.Flags = @var
FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Group.Flags" could not be bound.

Comment: I changed the start of the UPDATE statement to simply "UPDATE g" instead of "UPDATE dbo.Groups". Please try that.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you haven't specified the table name for the field "Flags" and it probably exists in more than one table in the query. Add the table name in the format "Tablename.flags" to the front of all references to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE g
SET g.Flags = @var
FROM
  dbo.Groups g
    INNER JOIN
  dbo.UsersGroups ug
    ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
    INNER JOIN
  dbo.Users u
    ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

- In the from clause - the update target needs to be the first table there.
- In the update clause - use the table alias created in the from clause.
- In the set clause - use the table alias created in the from clause.

I once knew the reasons that this dance needs to be done this way - now I just do it out of habit.  I suspect it has something to do with TSQL's double FROM clause in DELETE statements, and the possibility of talking about Two different instances of the Groups table between the FROM and UPDATE clause... or even Two different instances of the Groups table in the from clause (think self-join).

Answer (score 2):

Just do alias.Flags or TableName.Flags in the update statement.

So it becomes this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users
     SET Flags = @var
     WHERE UserName = 'UserA'

UPDATE g
   SET g.Flags = @var
FROM dbo.Users u 
INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g       ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE dbo.Groups Set dbo.Groups.Flags = @var FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN dbo.UsersGroups ug ON u.UserID = ug.UserID INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try 
SET Groups.Flags = @var in your second update

Answer (score 1):

youTableAlias.Flags

In your example: g.Flags

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround (albeit maybe not the best solution):

```
UPDATE dbo.Groups
SET Flags = @var
FROM dbo.UsersGroups ug INNER JOIN dbo.Groups g ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
WHERE ug.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'UserA')
```

Comment: Ah, ive just realised, its because Im trying to set the flags to SET dbo.Group.Flags = dbo. Group.Flags | 512

Comment: ok, i just used select g.Flags from 

  dbo.Groups g
    INNER JOIN
  dbo.UsersGroups ug
    ON g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
    INNER JOIN
  dbo.Users u
    ON u.UserID = ug.UserID
WHERE u.UserName = 'UserA' | 512

in place of the  dbo. Group.Flags | 512

Answer (score 0):

Mention the correct Table column for the ON clause to Condition

FROM database2.student student
LEFT JOIN database2.college college
ON student.college_id = college.college_id
ORDER BY college.college_id

This Error occurs due to the Name Confusion between the Table
Mention the Table column properly with the table Name
This would work..