# Ambiguous column name... but only sometimes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So apparently this has **Ambiguous column name 'LocationID':**

```
DECLARE @temptable table (LocationID int)
INSERT INTO @temptable SELECT LocationID FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO dbo.LocationsPlants (LocationID, PlantID)
(SELECT LocationID, PlantID FROM dbo.Plants CROSS JOIN @temptable)
```

Which I can fix by altering the bottom line to:

```
(SELECT T.LocationID, PlantID FROM dbo.Plants CROSS JOIN @temptable AS T)
```

But this identical query on another table does **NOT have ambiguous column IncotermsID:**

```
DECLARE @temptable table (IncotermsID int) 
INSERT INTO @temptable SELECT IncotermsID FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO dbo.IncotermsPlants (IncotermsID, PlantID)
(SELECT IncotermsID,PlantID FROM dbo.Plants CROSS JOIN @temptable)
```

I'm puzzled. Table structures:

dbo.Locations:

```
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocationTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](100) NULL
```

dbo.Incoterms:

```
    [IncotermsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Incoterm] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Always use table aliases and qualified column names -- especially if you have more than one table in the query.  Then you will never have to worry about this error.

Comment: And the definition for Plants?

Comment: Bingo, I forgot I had LocationID in Plants. NEED. MORE. COFFEE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous column name error, how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138239/ambiguous-column-name-error-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely a column named `LocationID` in the `Plants` table, which is why the query is confused as to which `LocationID` column to be returned, from `Plants` or from `@temptable`?

As @GordonLinoff mentioned, it's a good practice (I'd say best practice) to always alias your tables used in joins or correlated queries, and do so for their associated columns as well.

The reason this only happens "***sometimes***" is because in your second query, there is a single `IncotermsID` exists in only one table of the two used in your `CROSS APPLY`.