# Ambiguous Column Name 'plant'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to fix this error?. I've already tried looking for a double declaration of plant in my sql script, but there seems nothing wrong with my script. All other sql joins I made involving/having a column name ID work just fine anyway. Also when I try to run my original script which is this

```
select tblCustomerList.CustomerName, tblPackages.Package,tblChangeLevels.ChangeLevels,tblDevices.Devices,tblPlant.Plant

from ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCCB 

inner join ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCustomerList
on ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCCB.custAffected=ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCustomerList.ID

inner join ATPChangeControlBoard.tblPackages
on ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCCB.packageAffected=ATPChangeControlBoard.tblPackages.ID

inner join ATPChangeControlBoard.tblChangeLevels
on ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCCB.changeLevel=ATPChangeControlBoard.tblChangeLevels.ID

inner join ATPChangeControlBoard.tblDevices
on ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCCB.devsAffected=ATPChangeControlBoard.tblDevices.ID

inner join ATPChangeControlBoard.tblPlant
on ATPChangeControlBoard.tblCCB.plant=ATPChangeControlBoard.tblPlant.ID;
```

it works just fine and doesn't show any error on the plant column.

Below is the image screenshot of the actual code I used that shows the error.
Pls. Help. TIA. :)

[image]

Comment: Your screen shot looks like SQL Server so I removed the mysql tag.  Also, your question is basically non-sensical.  You've put in a query that works, but not the code that doesn't work.  No one is going to try reading your screen shot.

Comment: sorry about that BTW. The code that doesn't work is on the screenshot and don't know where in there. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous column name error, how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138239/ambiguous-column-name-error-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  didn't know about that.I will make sure next time to put the code in the code block instead of uploading the code in images. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer on another thread.

I change all the plant/[column name] declaration to tblPlant.plant/[tablename].[columnname] to directly differentiate between columns with the same column name.

In my case I change my code in the where clause from

```
 and (@plant is null or plant= @plant)
```

to

```
and (@plant is null or tblPlant.plant= @plant)
```

although the other sql joins didn't require me to add extra code like this, this one did so I  did so and just added extra code to the one that requires it.

I found the answer on a comment here, and since I can't upvote or comment yet, I just decided to emphasize here that it is what solved my problem. :)

[Ambiguous column name error, how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138239/ambiguous-column-name-error-how-do-i-fix-it/1138265#1138265)

by @JohnFx

he said that

"The problem is that you haven't specified the table name for the field "Flags" and it probably exists in more than one table in the query. Add the table name in the format "Tablename.flags" to the front of all references to fix the problem."